# How do I use NLog ILogger.Error(Exception, String,Object[])

Tags: nlog

NLog has a method `ILogger.Error(Exception, String,Object[])` [See Ref.](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.0.0/html/M_NLog_ILogger_Error_2.htm)

What kind of layout renderer can I use to log the args `Object[]`?

Alternatively, is there any other way to log all local variables?

Comment: The args Object[] will be included in the message as format string arguements. So basically NLOG will call string.Format(message, args) where message if your log message and args are the "fillers" in that message. I'm not aware of any automatic logging of local variables so you need to pass them manually to the Error method using the args paramter.

Comment: @nemesv Thanks! That answered my question. If you would reply this as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The args `Object[]` will be included in the message as format string arguments.

So NLog calls `string.Format(message, args)` where `messages` is your log message and args are the "fillers" in that message.

Then this formatted message can be accessed with the [`${message}` layout render](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Message-Layout-Renderer) to include in your logs.

I'm not aware of any automatic logging of local variables so you need to pass them manually to the `Error` method using the `args` parameter.